# Passing a matrix as a function argument

Tags: function-construction, matrix

I am trying to do the following:

```
q = Table[i + j, {i, 1, 15}, {j, 1, 10}];
normalize[mat_] := (temp = Transpose[mat[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]]];
  temp1 = Transpose[N[Map[Normalize[#] &, temp]]];
  mat[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]] = temp1; Return[mat])
q1=normalize[q];
```

I get the following error:

```
Set::setps: 
{{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},
{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},
{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13},
{5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},<<5>>,
{12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21},
{13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22},
{14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23},
{15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
{16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}} 
in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
```

Can you please help me in finding out what is wrong? I am new to *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To complement the other answer presented, I would like to suggest that it is often cleaner not to carry around additional symbols such as `temp` and `temp1` in your code.

If we want to modify a *copy* of the matrix we still need a "proxy" symbol which I will create with `Module`. (This is safer than `Block` as the latter will replace any symbols seen in the course of evaluation, even ones that are in the array; for example if `x` were in the array and I used `Block` it would conflict.)  You also do not need explicit `Return` except in special circumstances.

```
normalize[mat_] :=
 Module[{x = mat},
   x[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]] = 
     N @ Map[Normalize, x[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]]\[Transpose]]\[Transpose];
   x
 ]
```

Or, to modify the array in-place no proxy is needed, but `HoldFirst` is:

```
SetAttributes[normalizeInPlace, HoldFirst]

normalizeInPlace[mat_] :=
 (
   mat[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]] = 
     N @ Map[Normalize, mat[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]]\[Transpose]]\[Transpose];
   mat
 )
```

Comment: which is like faster then to use? is first one make copy of matrix which is bad for big matrix, so what to do now, use the holdfirst thing and pass by reference like in c, so no copy is made. copying large matrix is bad for memory. what to do?

Comment: @Robert I think you answer your own question, or am I mistaken?  If it is practical to modify in-place I surely would, but if you end up needing a copy of the original anyway that's something to consider.  Typically you will find that in-place modifications using `Part` are faster, especially when the percent of the array that is modified is small. (In this case it is fairly large, but if you were only modifying one row or column in a large array the difference would be clear.)

Answer (score 4):

## Answer

You can use the `HoldAll` attribute. Suppose I want a function that takes some list or matrix as input and sets its 4th element to `42`. This can be done like so:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[m_] := (m[[4]]= 42; m)
```

then

```
t = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 2}]
f[t]

(*
{{6, 2}, {7, 4}, {0, 4}, {10, 6}, {8, 7}}
{{6, 2}, {7, 4}, {0, 4}, 42, {8, 7}}
*)
```

In your case, it would be

```
ClearAll[normalize, q, q1];
q = Table[i + j, {i, 1, 15}, {j, 1, 10}];
SetAttributes[normalize, HoldAll];
normalize[mat_] := (temp = Transpose[mat[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]]];
  temp1 = Transpose[N[Map[Normalize[#] &, temp]]];
  mat[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]] = temp1; Return[mat])
q1 = normalize[q];
```

## Explanation

The [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute tells the evaluator not to evaluate the argument of your function before trying to do operations on it. Otherwise, look at what happens (using `Trace` which shows what is being evaluated):

```
ClearAll[f, g];
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[m_] := (m[[4]] = 42; m)

g[m_] := (m[[4]] = 42; m)

t = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5}]
f[t] // Trace

(*
{7, 6, 3, 7, 6}

{f[t],t[[4]]=42;t,{t[[4]]=42,42},{t,{7,6,3,42,6}},{7,6,3,42,6}}
*)
```

while without `HoldAll`,

```
g[t] // Trace
```

issues an error and dumps some stuff on the screen, most relevant of which (and immediately before the error) is this:

```
{7, 6, 3, 42, 6}[[4]] = 42
```

which is what causes the error. In the previous case, at this point there was a `t[[4]]=42` which is fine.

You can think of this as passing by reference, versus passing by value if the `HoldAll` attribute is not set (although this is not entirely accurate).

## Warning

Note that in this approach, you are manipulating the `t` that is in the global context. If you are writing more complicated code, you probably want to do what JM [described](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9079/16).

Answer (score 3):

You need *another* temporary variable to be able to do what you want:

```
normalize[mat_] := Block[{matTemp = mat, temp, temp1},
  temp = Transpose[matTemp[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]]]; 
  temp1 = Transpose[N[Map[Normalize, temp]]];
  matTemp[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]] = temp1;
  matTemp]
```

Note that in the line `mat[[2 ;;, 5 ;;]] = temp1` of the original code, the `mat` is replaced by the matrix you have given as argument, and since you can't assign to a matrix of a numbers, you get that error you saw.

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain this in terms of pointers? I was thinking, the function gets the pointer as reference and would modify the variable and return the pointer. Obviously, that is not happening. Can you please tell me what is happening?

Comment: There aren't any pointers here; this isn't C. To repeat: when you execute `normalize[]`, all instances of the pattern `mat_` are replaced by whatever argument you gave to `normalize[]`. Obviously, if the matrix of numbers that replaces `mat` appears to the left of `Set[]` (`=`), there will be an error, since you can't assign to a matrix of constants.