# Error with AppendTo

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to write a function that builds a graph, or - better said - adds a layer of leaves to a pre-existing graph.

Basically, I hand to the function three lists. `edges` is the "already existing (upper) part of the tree", `nodeslvl1` includes all its leaves, `nodeslvl2` are the new leaves, which should stem from the ones in `nodeslvl1` according to a certain rule.
The function should append the new edges of the tree to the ones already existing in the original `edges`. Finally, it should graph the tree.

Here's my code:

```
graphfrom2lists[edges_List, nodeslvl1_List, nodeslvl2_List] := 
Module[{i, l = Length[nodeslvl1[[1]]], pos},
  For[i = 1, i < Length[nodeslvl2] + 1, i++,
    pos = Position[nodeslvl1, nodeslvl2[[i,2;;l+1]]][[1,1]];
    AppendTo[edges, nodeslvl1[[pos]] -> nodeslvl2[[i]]];
    Print["edges becomes  ", edges];
  ];
 Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
]
```

When I try to run the code on an easy example (*), I get the following error:
`AppendTo::rvalue: {root->{2},root->{4},root->{6}} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed.`
I cannot understand the meaning of it, since my list of edges has a name, it's not like doing `AppendTo[{1,2,3},4]`!
Also, my code doesn't actually seem different from this other (properly working) one, which does the same thing, but building just the first two layers of such a tree.

```
graphfrom2listsbasic[nodeslvl1_List, nodeslvl2_List] := 
 Module[{edges = {}, i, j, pos},
  For[i = 1, i < Length[nodeslvl1] + 1, i++,
   AppendTo[edges, "root" -> nodeslvl1[[i]]]
   ];
  Print["edges is  ", edges];
  For[j = 1, j < Length[nodeslvl2] + 1, j++,
   pos = Position[nodeslvl1, nodeslvl2[[j, 2 ;; 2]]][[1, 1]];
   AppendTo[edges, nodeslvl1[[pos]] -> nodeslvl2[[j]]]
   ];
  Print["edges is  ", edges];
  Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

So what am I missing about the AppendTo command?
Thanks in advance!

(*) Here's the example, which is expected to produce the same result with both functions:

```
nodes1 = {{2}, {4}, {6}};
nodes2 = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 6}, {3, 6}, {5, 6}};
edgespartial = {"root" -> {2}, "root" -> {4}, "root" -> {6}};
graphfrom2listsbasic[nodes1,nodes2]
graphfrom2lists[edgespartial, nodes1, nodes2]
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a function that will modify its argument permanently?  E.g. using a simpler example, after evaluating `x={1,2}; addone[x]`, the value of `x` will have changed to, say, `{1,2,1}`.  This is how `AppendTo` works.  The more usual way of working in Mathematica is to leave `x` alone and *return* a modified list instead, just like `Append` does.  Both solutions are possible though.  Do I understand it right that you want to use the first one?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, you understood correctly. I want to modify the list `edges`, adding the additional connections for my expanded graph.

Comment: Add `e2 = edges` in the first argument inside `Module` (`Module[{e2=edges, ...},...]`, and change `edges` to `e2` in the rest (`AppendTo[e2,...]` and `Graph[e2,...]`.

Comment: In that case start by reading through [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html) up to and including "Nonstandard Evaluation" and understanding why `AppendTo` needs to have the `HoldFirst` attribute while `Append` doesn't.  See also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37175/passing-lists-to-functions-in-a-manner-that-works-like-pass-by-reference-in-othe). Then we can go from there.  In short, `f[x_]:=AppendTo[x,1]; arr={3,2}; f[arr]` will evaluate as `f[arr]` -> `AppendTo[{3,2}, 1]`, which causes an error.  The `HoldFirst` ...

Comment: ... attribute will allow it to evaluate to `AppendTo[arr, 1]` instead of `AppendTo[{3,2},1]`.

Comment: Please see specifically: [(18737)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/121)