# Why my variable j3[k][[1]] isn't affected?

Tags: core-language

I would like to understand why in this code :

```
    For[k = 1, k <= Length[Couples1],
  j3[k][[1]] = 6;
  j3[k][[2]] = 7;
  Print[j3[k][[1]]];
  k++;

  ];

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9
```

My variable `j3[k][[1]]` isn't affected to "6" ? It is just a code of example but I don't get why it does'nt work ?

Comment: See: [72624](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72624/5478)

Comment: The linked duplicate discuss `j3[[k]][[1]]` example while you have `j3[k][[1]]` but the issue is the same and should answer your problem. Let me know if you disagree. Also see the second link from comment and links from it to learn more if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I understood that Part is a too low level function to allows this. I can thus use AppendTo in my example. But Is there another function of "higher level" than part to allow me to do the same thing as j3[k][[1]] = 6; ?

Comment: E.g. `j3[k] = ReplacePart[j3[k], 1 -> 6]`