# Extract outputs from a WHILE loop in a table format

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, code-review, procedural-programming, coding-style

How can I convert my multiple outputs of a while loop in a table form and save it for later use. Here is a sample code:

```
i = 1;
While[i < 6, c = 2^i; d = 3^i; Print[c "           ", d]; i++]
```

The actual output should look like this:

[image]

Eventually, my goal is to eliminate certain rows based on a specific condition that values in column 2 satisfy.

(Here, my while loop is essential in what I am doing in my actual code. So assuming that cannot be changed is there a way to convert the output in table format? I apologize for any confusion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) instead of a `While` loop:

```
table = Table[{2, 3}^i, {i, 5}]
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 9}, {8, 27}, {16, 81}, {32, 243}}

Or

```
table = Transpose[Table[i^Range[5], {i, 2, 3}]]
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 9}, {8, 27}, {16, 81}, {32, 243}}

You can use [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) to display:

```
Grid[table, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:** If you have to use `While` you can [`AppendTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html) a list that is initialized to `{}`:

```
i = 1;
tab = {};
While[i < 6, AppendTo[tab, {2, 3}^i++]]
tab
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 9}, {8, 27}, {16, 81}, {32, 243}}

Alternatively, you can use [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) / [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) combination:

```
i = 1;
Reap[While[i < 6, Sow[ {2, 3}^i++]]][[2, 1]]
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 9}, {8, 27}, {16, 81}, {32, 243}}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the while loop is essential in what I am doing in my actual code (which I am not able to provide). Even with the while loop can I use the table function as you mention? Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @primefinder, please see the update.

Comment: Why is a `While` loop necessary? Could you use `NestWhileList`?

Comment: What about Reap and Sow @primefinder ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue for small lists such as provided in the example.  However, `AppendTo` has issues for large ones.

With that in mind, an alternative approach is to assign your output list before entering the `While[]` block as in

```
i = 1;
out = Range[5];
While[i < 6,
 out[[i]] = {2, 3}^i; 
 i++
 ]
out
```

Format, using `TableForm` or `Grid` as you like.

But as @kglr suggests, his first `Table[]` example is more typical of Mathematica. While you can write Fortran (C, Pascal, ...) in any language, often there are better approaches.

Comment: Could you expand on the AppendTo issues? Will it cause problems if I am storing say around 20 million outputs which are "large" numbers in a list generated using AppendTo ?

Comment: I'd refer you to this answer (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72624/why-can-appendto-modify-a-referenced-list-in-place-but-part-cannot) from @Leonid Schifrin.  "The reason is that AppendTo and PrependTo actually replace the whole list with a new one, rather than only changing a single element."