# Numerical integration with OwnValues

Tags: numerical-integration

Say I have a symbol with an `OwnValue`

```
a = y
```

And we define an integration like this

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*z*y, {z, 0, 1}]
```

Then calling `f[1]` results in an error, probably because of the `HoldAll` attribute of `NIntegrate`. Using `Evaluate[a]` does not help.

How can an integration like this be done correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example represents a practice which is best avoided. Namely, making a function implicitly depend on some variable is an invitation for trouble. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808) for a partial explanation of why.

The semantics of parameter-passing in *Mathematica* was described e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument/17770#17770). What happens is that the value of the parameter is *literally injected* into the body prior to the execution of the body. Therefore, in your definition, even if you define

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Evaluate[a*z*y], {z, 0, 1}]
```

the following will happen when you pass a value (say, call `f[5]`):

```
f[5] --> NIntegrate[Evaluate[a*z*5],{z,0,1}]
```

meaning that the binding of `y` to `5` happens in any case *before* the body executes, so `a` has no chance to fire. Therefore, `NIntegrate` does not know about the relation between `a` and the actual value of `y` you passed, and computes `a` to symbolic `y` during evaluation.

One possible way out is to define something like this:

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := 
   With[{a = y}, NIntegrate[a*z*y, {z, 0, 1}]]
```

This will work as expected. However, better still would be to only use in the r.h.s. of a function the parameters that you pass explicitly. Here this would look something like

```
ClearAll[a, f];
a[y_] := y;
f[y_?NumericQ, a_] :=
  NIntegrate[Evaluate[a[y]*z*y], {z, 0, 1}]
```

so that

```
f[5, a]

(*  12.5  *)
```

Comment: You gotta be kidding right? 11 mins after the OP posted the question. I did not even had the chance to read it ;-)

Comment: @halirutan Yesterday, I wanted to tell the same to Szabolcs twice (for his answers on array memory management, and on `Position` - the latter took him just 5 mins!).

Comment: @Leonid To tell the truth, I have already read the memory management question on SO, so I had a bit of advantage :)

Comment: @Szabolcs But that one wasn't the biggest surprise. The one on `Position` was - you managed to write a full-fledged answer with links and formatting etc, citations from docs - in under 5 minutes.