# Define a function with a function for an input

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to create the functions 
$even[f]$ and $odd[f]$ which will apply the formula $even[f(x)] = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ 
and $odd[f(x)]=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$ for an arbitrary $f$.

I tried using

```
even[ff, x_] := (ff[x] + ff[-x])/2
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What would the correct approach to this be?

Comment: `even[f_[x_]] := (f[x] + f[-x])/2` and `odd[f_[x_]] := (f[x] - f[-x])/2`

Comment: or like this: `even[f_] := (f[#] + f[-#])/2 &;

    odd[f_] := (f[#] - f[-#])/2 &`

Comment: Neither approach is working for me at the moment. In the first approach mathematica doesn't evaluate anything, just leaving the even function with whatever its argument is, and in the second approach I have a lot of #'s that are left unevaluated as well.

Comment: When I boot mathematica fresh and enter it in this is what I get:In[28]:= ClearAll[f, ff, even, x]

In[29]:= even[f_[x_]] := (f[x] + f[-x])/2

In[30]:= f[x_] := x^2 + x

In[35]:= even[f]
even[f[x]]
even[f[x_]]
even[f[#]]

Out[35]= even[f]

Out[36]= even[x + x^2]

Out[37]= even[x_ + x_^2]

Out[38]= even[#1 + #1^2]

Comment: When I type in manually, (f[x]+f[-x])/2 it produces x^2, which is what I want it to do. How do I make my manual typing in into something that isn't manual? I want to automate that.

Comment: I still have the same issue. I am running v.9 the student edition, would that a play a role at all?

Comment: Did you `SetAttributes` like I did?

Comment: I didn't notice that until now, sorry. Now when it works when I do it on a defined function. What is HoldAll doing in this context?

Comment: Related: [(17767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17767/121), [(18737)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/121)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[{even, odd}, HoldAll];
even[f_[x_]] := (f[x] + f[-x])/2;
odd[f_[x_]] := (f[x] - f[-x])/2;
```

**Usage**

```
g[x_] := x + x^2;

even[g[x]]
```

> x^2

OR as Szabolcs suggested using pure functions:

```
even[f_] := (f[#] + f[-#])/2 &;
odd[f_] := (f[#] - f[-#])/2 &
```

**Usage**

Using the same `g` as above

```
even[g][x]
```

> x^2

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that Szabolcs' method requires calling `even[g][x]` instead of `even[g[x]]`. Also it doesn't require `HoldAll`.

Answer (score 7):

You said you tried using

```
even[ff, x_] := (ff[x] + ff[-x])/2
```

but I guess you forgot to put the underscore on the first argument. If you do

```
even[ff_, x_] := (ff[x] + ff[-x])/2
```

instead, then it works.

```
g[x_] := x + x^2;
even[g, x]
```

> `x^2`

P.S. No `SetAttributes` necessary using this method.