# Jackson Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

Following an old post, I have tried to make a function that calculates the Jackson integral of $q$-calculus:

```
Clear[JacksonIntegral]; 
JacksonIntegral[f_[x_], q_, b_] := (1 - q) b Sum[q^j f[q^j b], {j, 0, ∞}]
```

When applied to

```
A[x_] := x^.25
```

I have no complaint but no evaluation. More generally, how could I make a new rule in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I'm positive this one is a duplicate now. [Possible duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42478/define-a-function-with-a-function-for-an-input).

Comment: I removed the first sentence, only because this is certainly not a dumb question.

Answer (score 6):

Your code should work with a small tweak. You just need to use the *name* of the function instead and input the name of the function or a pure function:

```
jacksonIntegral[f_, q_, b_] := (1 - q) b Sum[q^j f[q^j b], {j, 0, ∞}]
a[x_] := x^.25
jacksonIntegral[a, 1/2, 0.1]
(* 0.0485152 *)
jacksonIntegral[#^0.25 &, 1/2, 0.1]
(* 0.0485152 *)
```

Alternatively,

```
Clear[jacksonIntegral]
SetAttributes[jacksonIntegral, HoldFirst];
jacksonIntegral[f_[x_], q_, b_] := (1 - q) b Sum[q^j f[x] /. x -> q^j b, {j, 0, \[Infinity]}]
a[x_] := x^.25
jacksonIntegral[a[x], 1/2, 0.1]
(* 0.0485152 *)
```