# Defining Numerical Integral Functional

Tags: numerical-integration, operators

In some sense the question is a combination of [defining an operator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42478/define-a-function-with-a-function-for-an-input) and [defining numerical integration with parameters](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/define-a-function-via-numerical-integration-in-mathematica.532233/). For example, I want to define $I[f] = \int_0^1 f(x)dx$. and tried

```
I[f_?NumericQ] = NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

but it returns the error Nintegrate: ... non-numerical values for all sampling points ...

What's the right way to do that?

Comment: The function f has a Head of "Symbol" not "Numeric". Then, use `SetDelayed  :=` instead of `Set =` . Otherwise the integral will be evaluated at define time.

Comment: [`I`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/I.html) is a protected symbol and represents the imaginary unit.

Answer (score 2):

```
i[f_] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]

i[Sin]
(*    0.459698    *)

i[#^2 &]
(*    0.333333    *)
```