# Error: in the part assignment is not a symbol

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I am trying to set part of a Doubly-indexed list aInitialPopulation to cNumHeg. Specifically I am trying to set the 3rd part of the list aInitialPopulatiom[[cNodeNumber]] to cNumHeg.

My (attempted) implementation is shown below, any help as to why it isn't working would be appreciated.

```
cNumNode = 10;
cNumHeg = 3;
aInitialPopulation = initialPopulation[20, 10];(*A user defined function which creates a 20 by 10 list/array*)
addHeg[aPopulation_, aNode_, aNumHeg_] := (aTemp = aPopulation[[aNode]]; aTemp[[3]] = aNumHeg; aPopulation[[aNode]] = aTemp);
addHeg[aInitialPopulation, cNumNode, cNumHeg]
```

When I do this I get an error of the form:

```
Set::setps: in the part assignment is not a symbol.
```

It seems to be that I am trying to access part of a symbol rather than an array. I am not sure why this is - the code to modify the array works when it is not contained within a function definition. Any help much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Best,

Ben

Comment: `initialPopulation[20, 10];(*A 20 by 10 list/array*)` this does not create a 20 by 10 matrix. You need to use `Table` command to do that.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I should have been more clear here. This calls a function which creates a specified 20 by 10 list/array here. Best, Ben

Comment: The problem is that aTemp[[3]] is a number. And you trying to assign value to a number.

Comment: Answered in the "pitfalls" omnibus.  Specifically see: [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/121)  Also related: [(17767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17767/121)

Answer (score 5):

I have found the answer to my question. It is because I was trying to modify the value of x, rather than the name itself. A way round this is to make a copy of the variable, and operate on this. This below works:

```
addHeg[aPopulationImmutable_, aNode_, aNumHeg_] := Module[{aPopulation = aPopulationImmutable}, 
aPopulation[[aNode]][[3]] += aNumHeg; aPopulation]
```

Module here allows the variable aPopulation to be treated as local, and hence can be operated on.

Best,

Ben

Comment: +1 for posting an answer after finding your solution.