# How can an argument of the form f[t] be injected into the RHS of a function definition

Tags: function-construction, core-language

This is what I want, for an arbitrary function x

[image]

This is what I have done:

```
Wigner[f_[t_]] := 
  Integrate[f[t - τ/2] 
              Simplify[Conjugate[f[t + τ/2]], 
                Assumptions -> {t ∈ Reals && τ ∈ Reals }] 
              Exp[-I 2 Pi τ f],
    {τ, -∞, ∞}];
```

But this is what I end up getting:

[image]

Right now, I just want to get the substitution right.

Comment: I think you're using `f` twice in your expression, once for the argument of the Wigner function and once for `x`. Is `f` in the argument of `Wigner` supposed to be `x`? The problem is that `yy[t]` evaluates before getting plugged into `Wigner`. Are you okay with pure functions? And do you really need a value of `t` in there? Or is it okay if it spits back an expression with `t` in it symbolically?

Comment: You are correct, I made a type rewriting it, but it makes no difference at all.

Comment: @march https://i.imgur.com/4YRHeJr.png

Comment: It doesn't make a difference as far as the pattern-matching on the left-hand-side, sure, but it's worth making sure that we have the bigger picture in mind; it makes answering the question easier.

Comment: `Exp[t]` automatically evaluates to `Power[E, t]`, so that wouldn't match the pattern.

Comment: Related: [(17767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17767/121), [(18737)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/121)

Answer (score 3):

The solution may be to declare:

```
Attributes[Wigner] = {HoldFirst}
```

The point is to prevent Mathematica from computing the argument before applying the rules for Wigner