# Avoiding copies when modifying lists

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Consider the following approach to modifying a list:

```
updateList01[lst_List, test_] :=
 Module[{xs = lst}, If[test, xs[[1]] += 1]; xs]
lst = {1, 2, 3}
lst = updateList[lst, True]
```

The good: all arguments are passed explicitly. The bad: `xs` and `lst` are apparently both entirely in memory(?). If that is right, what is the *Mathematica* idiom to avoid building a (potentially large) second list? (Assume there are many lists that needed to be updated and that actual updating is more complex.)  Looking at [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html), it sounds like I might avoid a copy by setting `HoldFirst`. That is also how I am inclined to read [How to modify function argument?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767). Is that a correct interpretation? But even if one can avoid a copy this way, I'm clearly failing to understand something. The following fails:

```
SetAttributes[updateList02, HoldFirst]
updateList02[lst_List, test_] := If[test, lst[[1]] += 1]
lst02 = {1, 2, 3}
updateList02[lst02, True]  (* Not evaluated? *)
lst02   (* Unchanged *)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is yet, but it seems like the `Hold` attribute is preventing MMA from noticing that `lst02` is a `List`, so you're head specification isn't matched, which is why it's not evaluating. You'll also run into a problem because you actually want to modify what is located in `lst02`, try defining `updateList02[lst_Symbol,test_]:=...what you have`.

Comment: I guess the OP wants the updating function to remain pure so it can be applied to any lists, but also doesn't want the list to be duplicated inside the function. In other words, I guess he wants to pass just something like the *pointer* to a global list into the function à la C.

Comment: @Taiki, I think `Symbol` plays the role of the pointer here. If you want to check that the object represented by the symbol is a list you should do something like `update[lst_Symbol,test_]/;Head[ReleaseHold@lst]==List:= ...your function...`

Comment: @N.J.Evans Yeah I know. I just wanted to point out what the problem was, despite that your comment is already a fix to it. :)

Comment: @N.J.Evans, `Head` doesn't hold its argument so the `ReleaseHold` isn't required.

Comment: *Mathematica* is smart and it doesn't store duplicate arrays. Even explicit `lst03=lst02` is lazy. However there is one important (and weird) thing: set `$HistoryLength = 0` before dealing with big arrays!

Comment: @ybeltukov I this case however the modified list does cause a duplication, does it not?  At least that appears so in a quick test in v10.1.0.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, any modification of *packed* array causes its duplication. However you can partially modify list of packed arrays without a duplication. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73b44c53fe7e91d70d50) is my test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've actually got two problems. The first is the fact that the function isn't evaluating. This happens because you pass `lst02` to your function, which is a `Symbol` not, a `List`, so the pattern doesn't match your definition. You can see this by doing:

```
SetAttributes[updateList02, HoldFirst]
updateList02[lst_List, test_] := If[test, lst[[1]] += 1]
lst02 = {1, 2, 3}
updateList02[Evaluate@lst02, True]  
lst02   (* still unchanged *)
```

This evaluates, but not in the way you wanted it to.

Since you're trying to change the stuff referred to as `lst02`, write your function to accept the `Symbol` referring to the stuff you're trying to modify. But since you lost your original pattern match you'll need to make sure you only evaluate the function for lists, which you can do with a conditional:

```
ClearAll[updateList02];
SetAttributes[updateList02, HoldFirst]
updateList02[lst_Symbol, test_] /; Head@lst == List := 
 If[test, lst[[1]] += 1];
```

Now doing

```
lst02={1,2,3};
updateList02[lst02,True];
lst02
```

gives {2,2,3}

You can also use the conditional to add other safety measures, make sure your list is long enough etc.

Comment: The semi-documented `ListQ` can be used tersely with `PatternTest`: `updateList02[lst_Symbol?ListQ, test_] := . . .`