# Iterating KroneckerProduct[] and returning the result from a function

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, iterators, products

I am trying to write a function which will take a matrix m and an integer i as inputs. Then it will compute the Kronecker product of m with itself i times and return the result. The code is as follows.

```
m = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}});
multiQubitize[operator_, totalQubits_] := 
  Do[operator = KroneckerProduct[operator, operator], {i, 
    totalQubits}];
a = multiQubitize[m, 2]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Set::shape: Lists {{0,1},{1,0}} and {{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0}} are not the same shape.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the arguments inside the function, like you can with a subroutine in other programming languages. Make a local copy, use it, return it:

```
multiQubitize[operator_, totalQubits_] := Module[{optmp = operator},
  Do[optmp = KroneckerProduct[optmp, optmp], {i, totalQubits}];
  optmp];
```

A cleaner way is to use [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html):

```
multiQubitize2[operator_, totalQubits_] := 
  Nest[KroneckerProduct[#, #] &, operator, totalQubits];
```

Comment: +1.  It always boggles my mind when the argument is changed in some C code I'm using

Comment: [Well, you *can* "pass by reference".](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17770/2305) Whether that's the Mathematica way is a different question though.