# How to pass multiple results calculated in a module to global variables?

Tags: function-construction

For example, I defined a user function with a module and what this function does is take the values of two global variables `ga` and `gb` and write another two global variables `gsum` and `gdiff` with their sum and difference, respectively. How can I define a user function in the form

```
fun[a_, b_, sum_, diff_] := Module[ ...]
```

so that I can get `gsum` and `gdiff` written with the correct values when I call this user function by

```
fun[ga, gb, gsum, gdiff]
```

Assume that `ga=10` and `gb=5`.

I guess another way to put my question is, how to define a user function with not only input arguments, but also output arguments?

Comment: What you want is called "call by reference". You can find other questions regarding this topic using the search function. One example: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument

Comment: That is not a good way to program. Better be explicit always. Write your function to return the values needed. If you need to reset the global variabes, then write{a,b}=fun[a, b, sum, diff] and in fun at the end, return {a,b}. This way the function is clear what it is doing. Someone looking at this later, understand what it does. Setting/resetting global variables from inside modules can lead to problems and bugs.

Comment: @Nasser `AppendTo` 0_o

Answer (score 3):

You need [non-standard evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html). To do that, give your function the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html). Here is an example.

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[a_, b_, sum_, diff_] :=
  Module[{s = a + b, d = a - b},
    sum = s;
    diff = d;
  ]

ga = 10; gb = 5;
f[ga, gb, ga, gb];
{ga, gb}
```

> `{15, 5}`

Comment: @Kuba I edited this answer to address that.  m_goldberg, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well, that link is in opposition to: tutorial/Evaluation where they are part of standard evaluation sequence.

Comment: @Kuba I never claimed the documentation was not confusing. ;^)  That tutorial *also* has a section titled **Nonstandard Argument Evaluation** -- the terminology is suboptimal IMO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. 1) I don't mind at all. Your edit certainly improves the answer. 2) The term "nonstandard evaluation" has a long history. It goes all the way back to Lisp of the late 1950s. Even the earliest versions of Lisp had a special form QUOTE that stopped evaluation of an argument. I think it may be considered the ancestor of the various `Hold` forms of Mathematica.

Comment: @m_goldberg I did not know; thanks for the education.  I wonder if **The Standard Evaluation Sequence**, which *includes* hold attributes as Kuba points out, should have been called something else?