# Replacement in evaluation

Tags: replacement

(updated question) Question in short:

I have a data

```
x = 1
```

I have an expression

```
method:= (this=this+1; this)
```

I want to apply the method to data, by replacing `this` by `x`, and then evaluate `method`. So I want a function `func` such that

```
SetAttributes[func, Holdfirst];
func[method]
```

will evaluate `method` with `this` replaced by `x`.

---

(original question)I have a data:

```
data = <|x->1, y->2|>;
```

and a method

```
Clear[this];
changex[] := this[x] = 2;
changey[] := this[y] = 3;
```

I want to evaluate `changex`,`changey` with `this` replace by `data`.  I want a function `func` such that

```
func[ changex[]; changey[] ]
```

so that I have

```
data == <| x -> 2, y -> 3 |>
```

---

(1)  I tried:

```
SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst];
func[exp_]:= Block[{this}, this = data; exp; data = this];
```

this will lead to the correct result,`func[changex[]; changey[]]; data == <| x -> 2, y -> 3 |>` but it is not what I want. It copies the entire `data` to `this` (what I get is `this=<|x->1,y->2|>`), evaluate `exp` (get `this[x]=2;this[y]=3`), then copy entire `this` back to `data`. No real replacement happens during the evaluationg of `exp`.

(2) To prevent copying the entire data of `data` to `this`, I tried

```
SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst];
func[exp_]:= Block[{this, data}, this = data; exp;];
```

This time, I put `data` as a local variable of `Block`, so `this` is set to be the unevaluated symbol `data`. During the evaluation of `exp`, each symbol `this` will be replaced by the symbol `data`. If I run

```
func[changex[]; changey[]]
```

what I get is `Block[{this, data}, data[x]=2; data[y]=3;]`. Unfortunately, the symbol `data` is just a local variable whose downvalues are `HoldPattern[data[x]]:>2, HoldPattern[data[y]]:>3`. And outside `Block`, `data` is not affected.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17767/9490

Comment: The above link discussed the `Hold` attribute, which is related. In my trials, I set `data` as a local variable in `Block` to keep the unevaluated form, but it becomes a local variable, and I don't know how to access it from outside `Block`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for [`AssociateTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociateTo):

```
data = <|x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3|>;

AssociateTo[data, <|x -> 2, y->3|>];
data
```

> <|x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 3|>