# How does the parameters pass between functions?

Tags: functions, evaluation

In C++ , there are several ways to write a function:

```cpp
int foo1(int x){return x;} // copy,which is slow
int foo2(const int &x) {return x;} //quote,which is faster
int foo3(int *x){return *x;} // pointer in C
```

---

In Mathematica , when I use

```
x//foo1//foo2
```

Which way does mma use? Or mma use some other ways?

Comment: High-level languages basically all use pass-by-reference, but Mathematica does that then tries to pretend it's doing pass-by-value. You're really passing around pointers to some kind of `Expression` object, but when you modify one, Mathematica will copy it for you.

Comment: In short, Mathematica has the performance of the 2nd/3rd lines but the behaviour of the 1st line. To be precise, it uses copy-on-write. Many similar systems, like MATLAB, also use the same.

Comment: I would also recommend [this section](https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node173.html) of my book, as well as [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument).