# Why does the delayed functional assignment evaluate to `5=6`?

Tags: assignment

Why is it that

```
x=5
x=x+1
```

nicely evaluates to `6`, but the following

```
Remove[a,f,x]
a=5;
f[x_] := x = x+1
f[a]
```

evaluates to `5=6`?

To my understanding, the only way I can get the result I'm getting would if when I call `f[a]`, instead of first evaluating the LHS of from the "bottom to top", namely `<x> -> <5+1> -> <x=6> -> f[5] = 6` (while setting `x=6`), but it seems this is not what is happening. Is it because function substitution preceded over delayed assignment, namely it is substituting the value of `a` before evaluating `x=x+1`?

Comment: Because Mathematica evaluates eagerly rather than lazily. Arguments are always evaluated before passed to function, unless the function has a Hold attribute. Try `SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]`. Also try inspecting functions that modify variables, for example `Attributes[Increment]`.

Comment: With version 12.2, I get two error messages (`Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 5.`) followed by `True`. To see the evaluation sequence with your version, add `// Trace` to the last line

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node173.html), I was describing parameter-passing there in a rather detailed manner.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks a lot! I'm actually following that very same book to study mathematica, but haven't reach the section 4.4 :)

Comment: @onurcanbkts Well, that should mean that the way I laid out the material was not ideal - something to look into if I ever make a second edition :)

Comment: Have a look also at [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. It is a comment that contains an image that can't be put into a comment.

I can not reproduce your result. When I execute your code I get the result that I expected which is:

[image: eval]

I did m y evaluation in V12.1.1 on MacOS 10.13.4.

Writing `f[x_] := x = x + 1` doesn't really make much sense. The assignment will always fail, but `x + 1` will be returned. So `f[x_] := x + 1` produces the same result without issuing warnings.

Comment: İf you look at the trace of `f[a]`, you will see that it tries to evaluate `5=6`. Note that, I get the same error as you do, and my question is rather why it evaluates to this (I'm not trying to get around a problem, just trying to understand how mathematica works)

Comment: @onurcanbkts. `Trace` *tries* to evaluate `5=6`, but, of course it does't succeed. It considers that expression because you write `x = x + 1` on the rhs of your definition of `f`.