# How to assign values to a matrix by passing it to function?

Tags: functions

I have written a function to assign values to a matrix

```
putConj[arr_, i_, j_, val_] := Block[{},
  arr[[i, j]] = val;
  arr[[j, i]] = val\[Conjugate];
  ]
```

This makes $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ entry conjugate (handy for making a Hermitian matrix).
But when I pass an array, I get the `General::setps` error from the code below

```
hh = Table[0, 5, 5];
putConj[hh, 1, 2, 5];
```

> **General::setps {{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0}} in the
> part assignment is not a symbol**

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Look at this Q&A for the solution for your problem: [How to modify function argument?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17767). Does it duplicate your question?

Comment: @creidhne Yes, it does.